# Jquery UI effective tutorial

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resources, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Does anyone know a detailed and effective jQuery UI 1.7 tutorial out there?
I just can't do it with the demo page alone.

I can't figure out the drag and drop..
With just doing the `('div#item').draggable();`

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

i like this one:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/07/introduction-to-jquery-ui

also, try

```
$('div#item').draggable():
```

Comment: i forgot the dollar sign in me question.:D...sorry. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

To use jQuery draggable, you need to :

1. Include jquery.js, jquery.ui.core.js and jquery.draggable in your page
2. Declare a `<div id="item">Some content</div>`
3. Set a width and height to your div in your css : `#item { width: 100px; height: 100px; }`
4. Call the jQuery draggable() extension : `$('div#item').draggable();`

Of course, 2 and 3 can be done together:

```
<div id="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">Some content</div>
```